# Electricity production

Tags: electricity

Are there alternate means to produce electricity than magnetic induction?
I observe that all places this method is used .Do other methods exist even if this being the most profitable way.

Comment: Have you heard of [batteries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battery_%28electricity%29)?

Comment: You misunderstand my question.A similar setup to magnetic induction.Does such a way exists to produce electricity.In a battery we use chemicals to extract energy.

Comment: Exactly. Your question is: *"Are there other means to produce electricity than magnetic induction?"* The answer is: *"Yes, for example by chemical processes"* If that's not what you want to know, please rephrase your question.

Comment: Well if you understand what I meant to say.Please ans if you have it available.

Comment: A method similar to magnetic induction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Magnetic induction is by far the most efficient way to generate electricity, but there are other methods. The obvious common method is photoelectricity, as used in [solar panels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photovoltaic_panels). This is around 10% - 20% efficient.

There are plenty of other ways of generating small amount of electricy that have found specialist niches. For example the Voyager spacecraft use the Seebeck effect to generate electricity from heat. This type of electricity generation is generically known as thermoelectricity. Voyager uses a [radioactive source to generate the heat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radioisotope_thermoelectric_generator), but any source of heat will work.

Alternatively mechanical forces can generate electricity using [piezoelectricity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piezoelectricity). This is used to generate electric sparks in [gas lighters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas_lighter).

Or another method is [triboelectricity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triboelectricity), of which the most famous example is that schoolchild's favourite the [Van de Graaff generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_de_Graaff_generator).

And I'm sure there are many others I haven't thought of but commenters will add :-)

Comment: Don't leave out chemical sources ... a fuel cell lets you have a continuous process for converting chemical energy to electrical energy.

Comment: The OP seems prejudiced against chemical sources - see his response to [ACuriousMind's comment](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/127396/electricity-production#comment257731_127396).

Comment: Oh, I noticed. That's why I suggested a continuous process rather than a one-and-done.

Comment: @JohnRennie - real Van de Graaff accelerators (High Voltage Engineering - which was his company, or nowadays from National Electrostatics - pelletron.com) do not use tribocharging. Instead, high voltage inductors are used to put charge on the belt (classic HVE) or pelletron chain (NEC), often with a reversed polarity inductor at the terminal to double the charge transport.  Tribocharging would make lots of dust/particles which would mean opening and cleaning the pressure vessel more often.